# Pre selecting an item from drop down using a hash tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, hash

I have a registration page which the user enters with a #tag appended to the url like

```
mysite.com/registration#johnjackson
```

The hashtag is appended depending on what link was clicked to enter the registration page. The strings are always lower case and trimmed.

On the registration page there is a dropdown which I want to preselect from using js. It looks something like:

```
<select>
<option value="Sara Rush, Singer">Sara Rush, Singer</option>
<option value="John Jackson, painter">John Jackson, painter</option>
<option value="Albert Einstein, Pilot">Albert Einstein, Pilot</option>
</select>
```

I'm looking for a good solution to this. Maybe just going through the list of option values checking if the first 5-7 characters match the hashtag string?

Comment: Why don't you just give the option tags an id related to the anchor value of the hashtag? From there, `$("#selectID").val("johnjackson");` (you would have to give an ID to your select tag as well)

Comment: I don't have control over the page with the link, but that would of course make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var regex = new RegExp( hash, 'g' );
$('option').each(function() {
  var val = $(this).attr('value').toLowerCase();
  var matches = val.match(regex);
  if (matches) {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this almost does it I think. The problem is that the values contain commas and titles etc - and the hash string only contains the name. So only checking the first 7 characters would do it. 

Btw, since I'm not so good with Regex - does this strip the "#" from the hashtag string?

Comment: Yes it only gives you the value without the #. I purposefully left it simple to show a working example and leave it up to you to decide the level of comparison. For example, if you want you could lowercase and strip spaces and commas from both values and then compare them. If you don't strip out spaces and commas, 7 chars will be too long for really short last names.